# RecyclerView radiobutton

Tags: android

[image]
My Problem is that I want to see which radiobutton is selected in a separate radiogroup in the structure I made with RecyclerView and to reach the text in it, including invisible and visible ones.

the code i tried
found in the trailer

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = binding.recyclerView;
   Log.e("TAG", "viewButton recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()  : "+ recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()  ); // 9
    Log.e("TAG", "viewButton recyclerView.getChildCount()  : "+ recyclerView.getChildCount()  );// 5  

    for(int ii=0;ii<recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() ;ii++) {
ViewGroup vg1 = (ViewGroup) recyclerView;
       // Log.e("TAG", " vg1: " + vg1); // androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
ViewGroup vg2 = (ViewGroup) vg1.getChildAt(1);
      //  Log.e("TAG", "vg2 : " + vg2); // android.widget.LinearLayout
 ViewGroup vg3 = (ViewGroup) vg2.getChildAt(1);
        Log.e("TAG", "vg3 : " + vg3);// RadioGroup
for (int i = 0; i < vg3.getChildCount(); i++) {
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) vg3.getChildAt(i);
       // if(rb==null)continue;
        if (rb.isChecked()) {
         //   Log.e("TAG", "viewButton: " + rb.getText());
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the code to the question.